# Why 'and' and 'or' behaves differently with 0, 1, True, False?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logical-operators

Below is the scenario.

```
>>> False and 0
=> False
>>> 0 and False
=> 0
```

Both the conditions are same, but why is it returning different results?

```
>>> 0 or False
=> False
>>> False or 0
=> 0
```

Similarly, both the conditions should return same results, but why are they different?

The same applies in case of `True` and `1`

Comment: you are mixing boolean and integers

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Is there a specific order of execution when we use both bool and int?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ booleans are `int`s in Python, try `isinstance(False,int)`

Comment: As the dupe says "
    a and b returns b if a is True, else returns a.
    a or b returns a if a is True, else returns b.
"

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ `isinstance(False,bool)` and `isinstance(False,int)` returns same. Is it like, bool values are interpreted as integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, the`and, or` operators do not return boolean. They return the last thing evaluated. Since they are short circuit operators, the last thing that need to be evaluated for the expression `0 and False`, is`0`. Similarly, for `0 or False`, the last thing that needs to be checked is the second operand, `False`.

From the python documentation:

- `x or y`: if `x` is false, then `y`, else `x`
- `x and y`: if `x` is false, then `x`, else `y`
- `not x`: if `x` is false, then True, else False

Comment: if that where true then doing ***False and 0*** should return 0 and not False!

Comment: No, it should return False, since the `and` has already failed, it does not need to check 0.

Comment: OP is showing us that ***False and 0*** returns in fact ***False***

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: Again no, it returns False. The OP asked for `False OR 0`

Comment: Nope, the OP's snippet for `False and 0` does yield `False` as expected - it's `False or 0` that yields `0` (as expected again).

Answer (score 0):

Python conditional checking uses [Short-Circuit Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). This means the following:

```
False and 0
```

It is executing an `and` statement, so both elements must evaluate to 1. Since False doesn't, it does not check for the second one and it returns False. This also applies for `0 and False`, but since 0 is the first element it returns 0.

```
False or 0
```

In this case it is performing an `or` evaluation so one of the elements must evaluate to 1 (or True). Since False doesn't, it checks for the second operator (`0`) which neither evaluates to 1, so it returns it. The same applies for `0 or False`.

Here you have another approach that clears out any doubt. Using `0 or "Text"` it returns `"Text"` as it evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

`or` is a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is false. In the case, `False or 0`, first argument is evaluated to False, then second argument is evaluated, which is 0, and returns 0. This is valid for both the cases(`0 or False` too).

`and` is also a short-circuit operator, so it only evaluates the second argument if the first one is true. In the case `False and 0`, the first argument is evaluated to False, then the second is not evaluated and returns the first argument and vice versa.

For more [clarification, refer the docs.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not)